# List<Map<String,String>> to iterate through WebElement variables

Tags: java, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, datatable, cucumber

I am using a cucumber datatable:

```
When I populate a field with a new value
      | FieldName  | FieldValue |
      | Name | Joe Blogs |
      | Email address | jblogs@gmail.com |
      | Phone 1 | 04 555 6666 |
      | Phone 2 | 0800 123 4567 |
      | SMS Phone | 023 222 333 |
      | Fax number | 09 888 9999 |
      | Location | Bermuda Triangle |
```

With the following java class:

```
@When("^I populate a field with a new value$")
    public void ShouldPopulateFieldsWithValues(DataTable arg1) throws Throwable {
        List<Map<String,String>> data=arg1.asMaps(String.class,String.class);
        //Declare a string variable for NAME and assign it's value
        String profileNameTextboxValue = data.get(0).get("FieldValue");
        //Find the profile NAME text box
        WebElement profileNameTextbox = driver.findElement(By.id("name"));
        //Clear the value from the profile NAME text box
        profileNameTextbox.clear();
        //Send the string value to the profile NAME text box
        profileNameTextbox.sendKeys(profileNameTextboxValue);

        //Declare a string variable for EMAIL and assign it's value
        String profileEmailValue = data.get(1).get("FieldValue");
        //Find the profile EMAIL text box
        WebElement profileEmailTextbox = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
        //Clear the value from the profile EMAIL text box
        profileEmailTextbox.clear();
        //Send the string value to the profile EMAIL text box
        profileEmailTextbox.sendKeys(profileEmailValue);

        //Declare a string variable for PHONE1 and assign it's value
        String profilePhone1Value = data.get(2).get("FieldValue");
        //Find the profile PHONE1 text box
        WebElement profilePhone1Textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("phone"));
        //Clear the value from the profile PHONE1 text box
        profilePhone1Textbox.clear();
        //Send the string value to the profile PHONE1 text box
        profilePhone1Textbox.sendKeys(profilePhone1Value);

        //Declare a string variable for PHONE2 and assign it's value
        String profilePhone2Value = data.get(3).get("FieldValue");
        //Find the profile PHONE2 text box
        WebElement profilePhone2Textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("phone2"));
        //Clear the value from the profile PHONE2 text box
        profilePhone2Textbox.clear();
        //Send the string value to the profile PHONE2 text box
        profilePhone2Textbox.sendKeys(profilePhone2Value);

        //Declare a string variable for SMS Phone and assign it's value
        String profileSMSValue = data.get(4).get("FieldValue");
        //Find the profile sms phone text box
        WebElement profileSMSTextbox = driver.findElement(By.id("sms_phone"));
        //Clear the value from the profile sms phone text box
        profileSMSTextbox.clear();
        //Send the string value to the profile sms phone text box
        profileSMSTextbox.sendKeys(profileSMSValue);

        //Declare a string variable for Fax Number and assign it's value
        String profileFaxValue = data.get(5).get("FieldValue");
        //Find the profile fax text box
        WebElement profileFaxTextbox = driver.findElement(By.id("fax"));
        //Clear the value from the profile fax text box
        profileFaxTextbox.clear();
        //Send the string value to the profile fax text box
        profileFaxTextbox.sendKeys(profileFaxValue);

        //Declare a string variable for Location and assign it's value
        String profileLocationValue = data.get(6).get("FieldValue");
        //Find the profile Location text box
        WebElement profileLocationTextbox = driver.findElement(By.id("location"));
        //Clear the value from the profile Location text box
        profileLocationTextbox.clear();
        //Send the string value to the profile Location text box
        profileLocationTextbox.sendKeys(profileLocationValue);
}
```

The above code works, but surely there is a more efficient way to write the java class?

I was hoping that I could find a way to iterate through the WebElement variables with the different values from the datatable. Is there anyway to do this?

I found two examples of code, which I will try and adapt but not quite sure how to put it all together..

1st example:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : countries.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        // ...
        }
```

2nd example :

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list; // this is what you have already

    for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
    }
    }
```

Note: I am new to java / coding, any critique on the code would be helpful..

@homaxto, Taking instruction, I have created the following bean class Person..

```
public class Person implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Properties
        private String Username;
        private String Name;
        private String Email;
        private String Phone1;
        private String Phone2;
        private String SMS;
        private String Fax;
        private String Location;
        private String Address;
        private String Zip;
        private String PayPal;

    // Getters
        public String getUsername() { return Username; }
        public String getName() { return Name; }
        public String getEmail() { return Email; }
        public String getPhone1() { return Phone1; }
        public String getPhone2() { return Phone2; }
        public String  getSMS() { return SMS; }
        public String getFax() { return Fax; }
        public String getLocation() {return Location; }
        public String getAddress() { return Address; }
        public String getZip() { return Zip; }
        public String getPaypalEmail() { return PayPal; }

    // Setters
    public void setUsername() { this.Username = Username; }
    public void setName() { this.Name = Name; }
    public void setEmail() { this.Email = Email; }
    public void setPhone1() { this.Phone1 = Phone1; }
    public void setPhone2() { this.Phone2 = Phone2; }
    public void setSMS() { this.SMS = SMS; }
    public void setFax() { this.Fax = Fax; }
    public void setLocation() {this.Location = Location; }
    public void setAddress() { this.Address = Address; }
    public void setZip() { this.Zip = Zip; }
    public void setPaypalEmail() { this.PayPal = PayPal; }
}
```

My datatable is as follows:

```
Feature: Update my personal details
  As a Property Manager
  I want to update my personal details
  So that I can be reached by my customers

  @wip
  Scenario: Update my personal details
    Given I am logged in to my account
    Given I have navigated to the change profile tab
    When I populate a field with a new value
    | Username | Name        | Email         | Phone1     | Phone2       | SMS   | Fax  | Location         | Address        | Zip  | PayPal |
    | testy    | Test Logger | testerslog1@gmail.com | 04 555 6666 | 0800 123 4567 | 029 295 495 | 04 888 9999 | Bermuda Triangle | 5 Pokemon Lane | 9999 | testersLog1@gmail.com |
    Then I click save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like the following. For this to work you will have to use the ID of the input elements as the value in the first column.
If you have to have less dependencies in your datatable you could map this in your step implementation and look it up before using it.
Also you do not need a header row, and keeping you just need to skip the first row.

```
@When("^I populate a field with a new value$")
    public void ShouldPopulateFieldsWithValues(DataTable dataTable) throws Throwable {
        List<List<String>> rows = dataTable.asLists(String.class);
        // Either quit having a header in your datatable or remove the first row
        rows.remove(0);
        for (List<String> row : rows) {
            String fieldName = row.get(0);
            String fieldValue = row.get(1);

            // Use the IDs as name in your datatable
            WebElement profileNameTextbox = webdriver.findElement(By.id(fieldName));
            profileNameTextbox.clear();
            profileNameTextbox.sendKeys(fieldValue);
        }
    }
```

Another way going around this problem could be by turning around the table having the fieldnames as column names.

```
When I populate a field with a new value
  | Name      | Email address    | Phone 1     | Phone 2       | SMS Phone   | Fax number  | Location         |
  | Joe Blogs | jblogs@gmail.com | 04 555 6666 | 0800 123 4567 | 023 222 333 | 09 888 9999 | Bermuda Triangle |
```

With this design you can create a bean class "Person" with getters and setters for each column. Cucumber will do the [camel-casing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) and automatically call a method called setEmailAddress() etc. So if the header column is called "Email address" then Cucumber will call a method called `setEmailAddress` with the value `jblogs@gmail.com`.
This will give you the following implementation signature

```
@When("^I populate a field with a new value$")
    public void iPopulateAFieldWithANewValue(List<Person> persons) throws Throwable {
    for (Person p : persons) {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you might see this easily allows many rows of data.
Which one is best in your situation is entirely up till you, I just wanted to show the other option you have which is not as well documented.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I have implemented the above code (deleting rows.remove(0); and my header in my datatable) and it works perfectly. My only question is, given how we are using the ID's in the Cucumber DataTable, does this not make the test brittle? Besides that, thank you for the working code - I see how it all works now - much appreciated..!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question and what you mean with "brittle".
If your are worried about dependencies in your Cucumber steps and the code, you could map the Cucumber column with the HTML ID in a Map: [cucumberColumn:htmlId].

Comment: By brittle, I mean implementing ID's in the cucumber datatable. What if someone changed the cucumber datatable and did not realise that the first column consisted of ID's. But the mapping of the cucumber column with the HTML ID sounds like a good option. I will take a look into how to do this - thank you :-)

Comment: @JTester could you use the answer?

Comment: I think I like the second option better. As you said, it allows for more rows of data.. I am not sure how the class person will work, but I will google it and see if I can do it. Best way to learn :-) If I don't come right, I will ask for help again. Thank you!

Comment: I have created a bean class Person (see above), and changed my cucumber datatable. Does this look correct? You mentioned that "Cucumber will do the camel-casing and automatically call a method called setEmailAddress() etc." Could you explain what you mean by this? And how do I call my ID's - do I still need to use them as column headers in my datatable? Have not yet written my implementation, as I am still figuring out how to do this.

Comment: Yes, you still need the column headers - they are the ones using to identify the method to call.

Comment: Your help has been invaluable - thank you so much for showing me how to tackle this (in more than one way!).. Problem solved :-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. You are welcome to accept my answer to indicate to others that it was useful.